# Exibir a nota dos alunos em C

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Eu queria exibir a nota dos alunos quando fosse digitados todas as notas, em um array de 10 posições, eu tentei fora do for, mas ele me retorna só a última.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int notas[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("Digite a nota do aluno: %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
        printf("A nota do aluno %d e: %d\n", i, notas[i]); 
     //Ele exibe assim que digito a nota do aluno
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar outro `for` para mostrar a nota dos alunos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int notas[10];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Digite a nota do aluno: %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("A nota do aluno %d e: %d\n", i, notas[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[**`Exemplo`**](http://ideone.com/9EW9cX)

Comment: @user25141 Outro exemplo? para calcular a média, uma maneira é usar a [média harmônica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9dia_harm%C3%B4nica). [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60990/6454) tem um exemplo.

Comment: Vlw, vou testar aqui...